# Getting an array of ids from PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, postgrest

I'm attempting to make a database view (or function) which will allow me to get an array of database values. I'm using Postgrest to poll these views.

So far I'm using this:

```
CREATE VIEW api.value returns  as
select distinct on (value)
    value
from db.table
order by value;
```

This accomplishes the task of retrieving ids, although Postgrest will pop each in its own JSON like so:

```
[
    {
        "value":"xyz"
    },
    {
        "value":"zyx"
    }
]
```

Ideally I'd want just an array instead of multiple json entries like so:

```
[
    "xyz",
    "zyx"
]
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If your `value` column is of type `jsonb` then you can do :

```
CREATE VIEW api.value returns  as
select distinct on (value)
    jsonb_path_query_array(value, '$[*].value')
from db.table
order by value;
```

If your `value` column is of type `json` then it is a bit more complex :

```
CREATE VIEW api.value returns  as
select distinct on (value)
    jsonb_agg(val->>'value')
from db.table
cross join lateral json_array_elements(value) AS val
group by value
order by value;
```